# iOS App Development: Is there a way to make provisioning expiration time longer or to automatically renew it before expiration?

Tags: ios, xcode, enterprise-distribution

I'm currently developing an iOS-App in Swift and to debug it on a real device the app gets an entry in *Profiles & Device Management* under *General Settings*. However this entry seems to get lost at random points of time. Then my app won't launch anymore and instantly crashes, but when I start it with Xcode the entry appears again and everything works fine. So I never see a debugging error or something like that.
Do you have any ideas on how to fix or debug this?

// Edit: Is it possible that this has something to do with the expiration of *iOS Distribution Certificate* or *Developer ID Installer Certificate*?

// Edit 2: I now realized that the provisioning file that Xcode creates has such a short expiration time ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62D5a.png)). Is there a way to make this time longer or to automatically renew it before expiration?